# How can I select all fields of same type in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I was looking for the best way to collect all fields of the same type in pandas, similar to the style that works with spark data frames as below;

```
continuousCols = [c[0] for c in pysparkDf.dtypes if c[1] in ['int', 'double']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out with `continuousCols = df.select_dtypes([float,int]).columns` . If you have used any other method that works, feel free to add it as well.

Comment: `df.select_dtypes('number')`